# overload resolution failed because no accessible 'writealltext' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to edit "AM830.txt" with the users information that they enter into the Global****** variables

```
Public DestinationTick As String
        Public PlaneTick As String
        Public TimeTick As String
        Public NameTick As String
        Public DayTick As String
        Public Stockitems() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("AM830.csv")
        Public SortedStock(Stockitems.Length - 1)
        Public Stocktypes(Stockitems.Length - 1) As Flight

    Public Structure Flight
        Public Destination As String
        Public Plane As String
        Public Time As String
        Public Name As String
        Public Day As String
        Public Address As String
    End Structure


''' when they press the button names P1A1
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText("AM830.csv", "")
        If P1A1.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            Stocktypes(0).Destination = GlobalDestination
            Stocktypes(0).Plane = GlobalPlane
            Stocktypes(0).Time = GLobalTime
            Stocktypes(0).Name = GlobalName
            Stocktypes(0).Day = GlobalDay
            Stocktypes(0).Address = GlobalAddress
            P1A1.Enabled = False
        End If


For Each item In Stocktypes
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("AM830.txt", item.Destination & "," & item.Plane & "," & item.Time & "," & item.Name & "," & item.Day & "," & item.Address)
        Next
```

in the "My.Computer.Filesystem.WriteAllTest(...........) i get the error "overload resolution failed because no accessible 'WriteAllText' accepts this number of arguments" i have no clue what this even means??

Im very new to VB and this is my first program using files so sorry if this is a stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText need at least 3 parameters. You have to add True or False to indicate whether you want the text to be added to the existing text in the file or overwrite everything in the file. The correct way would be:

```
For Each item In Stocktypes
   My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("AM830.txt", item.Destination & "," & item.Plane & "," & item.Time & "," & item.Name & "," & item.Day & "," & item.Address,True)
Next
```

More info [My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27t17sxs(v=vs.90).aspx)